# Why does my code not work; Translating a pic

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}

\newcommand{\newvar}{\pgfmathsetmacro}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
    \newvar{\num}{5}
    \newvar{\val}{\num-1}

  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 0);
  \coordinate (C) at (0, 1);
  \coordinate (D) at (0, 2);
  \coordinate (E) at (1, 2);

  \tikzset{
        square/.pic={
            \draw[line width=1mm, pic actions]  (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;
        }
    }

    \tikzset{
        tile1/.pic={
          \foreach \i in {(A), (B), (C), (D), (E)}{
            \draw \i pic {square} ;
          }
        }
    }

  \begin{scope}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\num}{
            \foreach \j in {0,...,\val}{
                \path (3*\j+\i, -\j+3*\i) pic {tile1};
            }
        }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

First I have defined `square/.pic` which is just the outline of the unit square.

Then I have defined the coordinates (A), (B), (C), (D), and (E).
These are defined in such a manner that if the unit square is placed at each of these coordinates, then the resulting figure is a C-shaped tile.
This is carried out in `tile1/.pic`.

At the end of the code one can see two for loops, which were supposed to place various translations of `tile1/.pic` on the plane, achieving a tessellation.

However, the output I get is the measly:

[image]

PS: Please feel free to offer any general coding advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot translate symbolic coordinates like this, and here is no need to use these. (Also I would not use your command `\newvar`. It sort of works accidentally. And I removed packages and libraries that are not in use.) The following works.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\newvar}{\pgfmathsetmacro}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\num}{5}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\val}{\num-1}

  \tikzset{
        square/.pic={
            \draw[line width=1mm, pic actions]  (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1) -- cycle;
        }
    }

    \tikzset{
        tile1/.pic={
          \foreach \i in {(0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(0, 2),(1, 2)}{
            \draw \i pic {square} ;
          }
        }
    }
  \begin{scope}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\num}{
            \foreach \j in {0,...,\val}{
                \path (3*\j+\i, -\j+3*\i) pic {tile1};
            }
        }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the solution and various suggestions.